# radio button jquery ie6 problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

i am dynamically creating radio  using jquery as shown belown.
but they value only selected in ff,ie8.
ie6,ie7 not selecting the values.
how can i select the radio button value in ie6/7.

```
rand=$("<input type='radio' ></input>");
rand.attr("checked","checked");
$(document).append(rand);
```

Comment: Did you find what was wrong with it?

Comment: rand=$("<input type='radio' >");
my html to create radio box is worong
pestaa was correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `<input>` does not have a closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

Also give it a `name` attribute. If need be, set the `checked` attribute after appending to the DOM.

You could also do it like so

```
rand=$("<input type='radio' checked='checked' name='radio'/>");
$(document).append(rand);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the missing `name` attribute as Russ Cam mentioned, and also losing the `</input>`, your radio button should also have a `value`. My guess is the browser relies on value especially for radios, to implement the "only one can be checked at a time" functionality...

Good luck!